# Gradle test on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, gradle

I'm trying to run unit tests on an iPhone using a gradle script. The following script code runs the simulator tests okay, but how do I specify the platform of the physical device?

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->

    if (taskGraph.hasTask(test)) {

        println "\nCONFIGURE INTEGRATION"
        xcodebuild {

            destination {
                platform = 'iOS Simulator'
                name = 'iPhone.*' // all iphone sims
                os='8.*'
            }
            destination {
                platform = 'iOS'
                name = 'myPhoneName'
                os='8.*'
            }
        }
    }
}
```